# Is the Simpsons a cartoon or live-action show in the Futurama universe?

Tags: futurama, cartoon, the-simpsons

It is established here [Does Springfield still exist in the Futurama future?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19662/does-springfield-still-exist-in-the-futurama-future) that the Simpsons is a show in the Futurama universe.

Is it live-action or animated ?

Comment: Since the characters in Groening shows appear to *us* less realistic than actual actors, and the Simpsons characters appear to have the same degree of realistic appearance as the Futurama characters, I would assume it would have to be live-action. Other than that, I don't think there is any information to tell.

Comment: How often do we make dolls of live action characters? I have this feeling that Simpsons is not live action in futurama.

Comment: @bitmask Ah but isn't [Itchy and Scratchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Itchy_%26_Scratchy_Show) considered a cartoon?

Comment: @user606723 star wars and star trek, dr who, stargate come directly to mind. Then things like green lantern live action movie had a whole slew of action figures. In short where there is money to made in merchandising, merchandise will be created, which dolls and/or action figures play a large role in animated or live action... go sci-fi collecting geeks!~~~

Comment: @NominSim: Good point. Didn't think of that.

Comment: Aren't they shows in each others' universes? Simpsons is a show in the Futurama 'verse, and Futurama is a show in the Simpson's 'verse. (Matt Groening appears in an ep of The Simpsons and is introduced as "The creator of Futurama.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was answered by the creators [here](http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/23929909/highlight/275846) at time 19:20!

Unfortunately, this link is now broken.   If anyone can supply a working link to the video, please edit.

Luckily, I have preserved the relevant quote.   (This is why link-only answers are frowned upon.)

## It is a cartoon.

Matt Groening:  *The Simpsons are a cartoon.  They're a cartoon!  Yes!  Futurama is real.  Come on!   The Simpsons are yellow.*

Comment: I'm confused; isn't this exactly the same as DavRob60's answer? Broken link and all?

Comment: @JasonBaker:   Not it is not because it actually contains the useful quote from the horse's mouth.   As it stands, that answer contains no information, just a blank assertion.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't see the point. But hey, it's your question

Comment: @JasonBaker:   The point is simple.   This answer contains a quote.   In its current form, with the broken link (not its fault of course), the other answer has no information in it.  It's a link only answer which is exactly the reason for the guideline.

Answer (score 22):

This was answered in the [Futurama live event](http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/23929909/highlight/275846) (see at 29:18) :

Matt Groening said they are cartoon.

Comment: To be fair, @Sahuagin had the _correct_ answer already, which was confirmed when the question was asked during the event. It seems fair that **he** be given the accepted answer, and this "proof" should be appended to his answer. IMO.

Comment: But Sahuagin's answer is speculation, mine is word of God!

Comment: References are everything.  Cited claims beat uncited claims every time.

Comment: Link is dead. Any chance of a re-up?

Answer (score 12):

There is no reason to think that it is any different than it is in our universe, in fact as far as I know in Futurama all of 20th century pop-culture is identical to real 20th century pop-culture; this is a key point of the show: comparing the real 20th century to the fictitious 31st century.

Also consistent with it being a cartoon is the fact that the Bart Simpson dolls in `A Big Piece of Garbage` have the same voice and appearance as our version of Bart Simpson.

Answer (score 2):

I have just seen the episode where a ball of garbage sent in the space twentieth century risks falling back on New New York after one thousand years or so journey in the galaxy.
Our heroes are sent to the garbage "asteroid" with a bomb, in order to blow it up, Fry finds a pile of Bart Simpson's puppets and recognizes him.
Clearly the Simpsons have been a popular show in Futurama universe.

Comment: I'd extend this by noting the Bart doll retains the yellow skin coloring, which would be unrealistic in Futurama's universe. I think it's safe to assume it's still a cartoon show.

Comment: The question doesn't ask whether it is a show or not, but whether it would be a "cartoon" or "live-action" show in universe. The linked [question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19662/does-springfield-still-exist-in-the-futurama-future) already has established that it is a show.

Comment: @BenBrocka:  ...and I also doubt you can call any particular skin colour "unrealistic" in the Futurama universe.

Comment: @ThePopMachine for humans? Humans in Futurama all have quite "normal" skin colors and none of them are yellow.

Comment: @BenBrocka Actually, using updated information, if it was a live show, then it's ground zero for "Simpson's jaundice", which fry contracted in the newer seasons.